# Powershell 2.0 - how to get the timestamp when a local user account was disabled

Tags: powershell, local, account, adsi

I'm struggling finding information on how to find the timestamp when a local user account was disabled.
I need to implement an automation script that will remove the local user accounts that have been disabled more than x weeks ago. This script will run on multiple versions of Windows and a big number of machines, so we can't rely on newer version of Powershell, nor even to install and import modules like Active Directory.
So I'm left with working using with Powershell 2.0 with ADSI or Win32 functions.
Also checking the event logs is not possible because they are deleted every week.
Is there a way to identify this date?

Something similar like last login:

````
```Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'" | Select *```
````

or

````
    $computer.PsBase.Children | Where-Object {$_.SchemaClassName -match "user"} |
    Select-Object @{Name="ComputerName"; Expression={$computer.Name}},
                  @{Name="User"; Expression={$_.PsBase.Properties.Name.Value}},
                  @{Name="Description"; Expression={$_.PsBase.Properties.Description.Value}},
                  @{Name="Disabled"; Expression={[bool] ($_.PsBase.Properties.Item("userflags").Value -band 2)}},
                  @{Name="LastLogin"; Expression={[datetime]$_.PsBase.Properties.LastLogin.Value}```
````

Comment: The timestamp of when a user is disabled is not stored in the user object. That information is in the audit log.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Also I've seen until now that you can retrieve that info from the event log. Still I've read that there are some workarounds using the Last Changed date. I know that this might have inconsistent information, but is there a way to retrieve this date without importing the AD module?

Comment: You're talking about **local** users, so why do you think you would need the ActiveDirectory module?

Comment: 1) The AD module does not work with local accounts. 2) Without the audit data, there is no "workaround" for finding out when an account was disabled. Last change date is not equivalent to when an account was disabled unless you can guarantee that the last change to that account was to disable it.

Comment: Theo, because with that module you have more properties and functions that can help you with more advanced information.